# Setup Sharepoint 2013 with Google authentication without using Azure (ACS)

Tags: sharepoint, foundation, google-account

Can any one guide me step by step to configure and set up Sharepoint Founbdation 2013 with Google authentication.

Note: I do not want to use Azure i.e. ACS for this. But I m open to using any third party website/code which does this job and has a free licence and can be hosted anywhere. ie on my own server.